# Convert string to date format 105 in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, date-conversion

I had string in the order of ddmmyy i.e '231013' which i need to convert it into dd-mm-yy format
I tried following but it is giving yyyy-dd-mm format

I know  105 will give dd-mm-yy format

```
    DECLARE @ITEMS AS NVARCHAR(10)='231013'

    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@ITEMS,105)
```

but it is returning

2023-10-13
How to convert string in the order of ddmmyy to date dd-mm-yy

Comment: Are you trying to convert your string to a `DATE` data type? Or are you trying to convert your string to another string in a different format?

Comment: When you convert something *to* a `date`, it no longer *has* a format - it's a native type that properly encodes a date value. What you're then seeing is what the *client* tools are doing when they're asked to display a `date` - they have to convert it into a string - and what you're seeing is the way that the tools will *always* convert a `date` value into a string. You can't change the format that they're using.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert string in the order of ddmmyy to date dd-mm-yy**

```
DECLARE @ITEMS AS NVARCHAR(10)='231013'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),
CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 3, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 5, 2), 5),5)
```

result will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `mmddyy` style is [not natively supported](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) by CONVERT; to perform the conversion, I would just adapt the input string to one of the supported styles, like `mm-dd-yy`:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 3, 2) + '-' + 
                 SUBSTRING(@ITEMS, 5, 2), 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the format (Not converting to a DateTime type), you could `Stuff()` it:

```
Declare @Items as nvarchar(10)='231013' --ddmmyy

Select Stuff(Stuff(@Items,3,0,'-'),6,0,'-')  --dd-mm-yy
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24236)**